# IIS 7.5 AutoStart Feature doesn't work

Tags: iis, autostart

I am new to IIS 7.5, and I'm trying to use the AutoStart feature, as described in [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) and MSDN.

I implemented my own `Preload()` in my own `IProcessHostPreloadClient` and I just print to the log and event viewer there. 
But it seems I never reach the `Preload()`, since nothing is being printed. I expect to see the prints when I restart the Application Pool, but, as I said, nothing is happening.

Any suggestions as to what he problem could be? Or how can I check the reason for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> I just print to the log and event viewer there

That could be your problem. Are you sure you can write to the event log at all from within your web app? Traditionally you won't have enough permission to do it in an asp.net app hosted in IIS running the standard permissions.

Try putting a test page in your web app that writes to the event log to make sure your print to event log code is working. If it's not, can you go the simple option of writing a text file to your app_data folder? You've normally got enough permission to write to it.